# Reviewing text files stored GitHub LFS

Tags: github, git-lfs

We use GitHub pull requests to review both code and experiments in Jupyter Notebooks.

One thing we often found useful was possibility to review and comment single lines in notebooks.

Some notebooks are pretty large files, so we have decided to migrate them to Git LFS. Unfortunalety, GitHub does not provide a way to comment/review lines of text files stored in GitHub LFS.

Is there a way to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, as [documented by GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/collaboration-with-git-large-file-storage). The recommend checking out the changes and reviewing them locally.

It might be possible to work around this using a browser extension, but I couldn't find any for this purpose so far.